# Удаление подпапки из адресной строки

Tags: .htaccess

Есть папка с файлом вида:

```
site.ru/page/test.php
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в адресной строке отображалось `site.ru/test.php`, и при этом папка и файл физически оставались на своих местах?

Пробовал это сделать через .htaccess. Встречал конструкцию вида:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^page/test.php/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/test.php/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test.php/$ /page/test.php/ [L]
```

Конструкция не универсальная, но и она не работает. Все, что удалось добиться, это убирание page посредством такого редиректа:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/page/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Подскажите, что можно предпринять?

Comment: Для чего в конструкции `^test.php/$` присутствует символ "/" ?

Comment: Встречал такую конструкцию на другом ресурсе и она у человека работала. Без символа "/" пробовал - не работает.